# Multiple modals with links

Tags: javascript, css, http

I've have multiple modals in a page, and I want that these modals have their own links so that I can share a link directly to that open modal

The basis of my code is this from W3 School https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FXW3ATN4D33U

I read that this code do this but I cant make it work

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  if (window.location.href.indexOf('#myModal') != -1) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
  }

});
```

Comment: do you want to show modal for every buttons, for example if you have three buttons, is three buttons should open three different modals. Refer this link http://jsfiddle.net/cazepeda/4euakd8m/

Comment: I already have modals in buttons. What I need is that when I click and open the modal the page link will change to something like that example.com/#modal4